# Retirar tags de uma variavel varchar php

Tags: php

Tenho um variavel php varchar que possue um html.Consta uma tabela, nessa tabela nos 'td' existe um classe "desaparece", queria que todas as tags que possuísse esta classe fosse retirado da variavel php.

Antes:

```
  $varaiavel = "
 <table>
  <tr class="header">
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">Código</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Nome do professor</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">Coordenação</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">Telefone</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">Email</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">12</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Paulo Rodolfo</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">(63)33131221</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">T(63)33131221</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">paulo.webrall</td>
  </tr>
```

";

Depois:

```
 $varaiavel = "
 <table>
  <tr class="header">
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Nome do professor</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">Coordenação</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">Telefone</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">Email</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Paulo Rodolfo</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">(63)33131221</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">T(63)33131221</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">paulo.webrall</td>
  </tr>
```

";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso você precisará das classes [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) e [DomXPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php):

```
<?php

$variavel = '
 <table>
  <tr class="header">
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">Código</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Nome do professor</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">Coordenação</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">Telefone</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">Email</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">12</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Paulo Rodolfo</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">(63)33131221</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">T(63)33131221</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">paulo.webrall</td>
  </tr> ';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$dom->loadHTML($variavel);

//use DomXPath para encontrar os tds com o class name
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname='desaparecer';
$xpath_results = $xpath->query("//td[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

//para cada match ele exclui a tag
foreach( $xpath_results as $td ) {
    $td->parentNode->removeChild($td);
}

//o documento final
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: muito obrigado .

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar as classes DOMDocument e XPath para encontrar e remover os nodes (nós):

**Para a váriavel:**

```
$variavel = '
 <table>
  <tr class="header">
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">Código</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Nome do professor</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">Coordenação</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">Telefone</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">Email</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
      <td class="check"></td>
      <td class="campo_grid_1 desaparecer">12</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_2" style="width:30%">Paulo Rodolfo</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_3" style="width:30%">(63)33131221</td>
     <td class="campo_grid_4" style="width:10%">T(63)33131221</td>
      <td class="campo_grid_5" style="width:20%">paulo.webrall</td>
  </tr> ';
```

**Pegando o objeto do documento:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($variavel);
```

**Localizando os nodes com classname desaparecer:**

```
$xpathsearch = new DOMXPath($doc);
//Buscas com XPATH precisam ser especificas
$nodes = $xpathsearch->query('//td[contains(@class,"desaparecer")]'); 
foreach($nodes as $node){
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
};
$variavel_limpa = $doc->saveHTML();
```

**$variavel_limpa** é o resultado que você deseja.

**Refs.:**

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

[DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domxpath.query.php)

[Remove a Node Using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839656/remove-a-node-using-xpath)

Comment: obrigado ......